# Remote desktop connection by host name vs IP address

Tags: remote-desktop

Is there any difference at all connecting to remote desktop via host name or ip address, other than an initial dns lookup for the former?

i've been having a a strange issue using rdp over cloudflare zero trust.

say the host name in the internal network is host.example.com. its ip is 192.0.0.10. on the client host.example.com always resolves to 192.0.0.10. other services such as web service (http://host.example.com) work just fine.

when connecting to host.example.com remote desktop, i get the initial NLA login popup and then it hangs on securing remote connection forever. but on rare occasions it connects.

but no issues when specifying 192.0.0.10 for remote desktop, it always works.

so back to the original question, is there a difference in how rdp treats connecting using a host name vs a host ip address other than a simple normal initial dns lookup? i wouldn't think so, but now having doubts.

Comment: You should probably specify if you are subscribed to and using the private subnet routing over WARP using the WARP client installed on the endpoint, public hostname routing, or both.

Comment: Cloudflare Tunnel can also route applications through a public hostname, which allows users to connect to the application without the WARP client. This method requires having *cloudflared* installed on both the server machine and on the client machine, as well as an active zone on Cloudflare. The traffic is proxied over this connection, and the user logs in to the server with their Cloudflare Access credentials.

The public hostname method can be implemented in conjunction with routing over WARP so that there are multiple ways to connect to the server. You can reuse the same tunnel for both.

Comment: https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/connections/connect-networks/use-cases/rdp/#connect-to-rdp-server-with-cloudflared-access

Comment: `when connecting to host.example.com remote desktop, i get the initial NLA login popup and then it hangs` probably a good idea to perform a packet capture to confirm what it is communicating with. We're assuming that domain and host name is only present at the endpoint you are connecting to and not associated with something else.

Comment: using private subnet 192.0.0.0/24. cloudflared installed on a host inside the network but not the target rdp host. as mentioned i can always remote into the target host via priv ip and strangely on rare occasions via host name. looks like i need fire up wireshark after all. but first wanted to be sure about any possible differences in using rdp with host name vs ip. and there really should be no difference as long as the host name resolves correctly.

Comment: In a traditional environment, using an IP address typically cannot use Kerberos. That is one difference. Using TLS is a bit more complex.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is the security certificate that is bind to the name usually. To see which one is used, see here; “Certificates (Local Computer)”->"Remote Desktop"->"Certificates"

Thus it should only impact the NLA warning. For a RDH/TS server you would want the client to connect to the correct FQDN name to prevent a warning, and to be able to install the certificate to the user store, but for an admin session its not an issue.

Comment: very helpful suggestion, but the cert wouldn't be the issue here. internally i can reach the host using all kinds of host names as long as they resolve to the host's ip. the cert warning pops up, i click don't-ask-me-again and continue or i have the authentication  warning  disabled on the client. again i can always connect via ip and on rare occasions via the host name. this issue must be related to the cloudflare tunnel.