# Remote Desktop intermittent connection issues

Tags: tcp, remote-desktop

this post is related to this:[Remote desktop connection by host name vs IP address](https://serverfault.com/questions/1146486/remote-desktop-connection-by-host-name-vs-ip-address)

but there's more info to be presented so decided to post a new one.

when connecting to remote desktop using the **hostname**, it often hangs on "securing remote connection...". this is the wireshark capture:
[image]

but when the connection succeeds, which is sometimes when hostname is used and always when **ip address** is used, this is the capture:
[image]

notice the **psh,ack** on the first capture. then it hangs after the last captured packet.

in the second case it connects and then functions normally.

22222 is just the remote desktop port on the target win10 machine, changed from 3389. client machine is also win10.

any ideas why it often gets stuck, but only when the hostname is specified in mstsc.exe?

Comment: Which version of Windows? Are server and the client up to date?

Comment: both ends are win10 pro 22h2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I've finally resolved this issue and the solution will stretch credulity.

For some reason I remembered a long time ago when disabling TCP autotuning had helped with a network issue. So I disabled it on my Win10 client:

```
netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled
```

After a reboot the remote desktop issue was magically resolved. Obviously disabling autotuning also adversely affected the throughput, so I enabled it again and rebooted.

```
netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=normal
```

It's been a few days now and all is fine accessing remote desktop using the hostname.

Still makes no sense that using the host's IP address was and still is fine all along.

Could toggling TCP autotuning on my Win10 client have cleared out some network hurdle? I have no idea, other than it fixed the problem.